# Magento 2: Product Collection based on news_from_date

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection

I want to get the product collection of those that have news_from_date field.

This is my block file

```
<?php
namespace Company\Mod\Block\Theme;
class Productnew extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
        ) {

        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getProductCollection()
    {       
        //echo 
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $todayDate  = date('Y-m-d', time());
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate));

        return $collection;
    }



}
```

In my phtml

```
<?php 

 $test = $block->getProductCollection();
 print_r($test);exit;
```

But it returns a blank page. How do I get product collection correctly?

Comment: If you view the source it will often give you the error message. Or make sure developer mode is turned on.

Comment: @V.P  please try with below solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}

protected function getProductCollection()
    {
       $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
       $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
       $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ])->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        );

        return $collection;
    }
```

Inside template file,

```
<?php 

 $test = $block->getProductCollection();
 foreach($test as $product){
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getPrice();
    print_r($product->getData());
 }
```

Remove var folder and clear cache.

Comment: In my phtml,I have used this $test = $block->getProductCollection();echo 'yyyyyyy12'.count($test);But it gives yyyyyyy120 as result,which means count is zero.Please help

Comment: have you set product as new date from backend?

Comment: yes i have set. Also,for testing I have  returned $todayDate .It gives null value

Comment: use only,  $todayDate = date('Y-m-d'); and check

Comment: I got today's date.I have cleared the cache as well.I got the product count also.Can you please help me to get the product name and price in that phtml for that collection. I have used $test->getName(); .But giving error.

Comment: @V.P please check my updated answer and if you work please accept as answer so other user have usedful in future.

Comment: Array as followsArray ( [entity_id] => 2052 [attribute_set_id] => 4 [type_id] => simple [sku] => Saceam mirea dacema giren [has_options] => 1 [required_options] => 1 [created_at] => 2016-01-27 16:00:04 [updated_at] => 2016-08-15 19:52:58 [news_from_date] => 2017-03-01 00:00:00 [is_salable] => 1 ) .It  has no name and price and product image

Comment: Have you checked, echo $product->getName()?

Comment: Yes. But it has no value. In that array name is not there.